# convert jsonx array to xml in xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, jsonx

My input XML would be like this

```
<json:object xmlns:json="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/2009/jsonx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <json:object name="Login">
        <json:array name="Group">
            <json:object>
                <json:string name="Name">john</json:string>
                <json:string name="Password"/>
            </json:object>
            <json:object>
                <json:string name="Name">john</json:string>
                <json:string name="Password"/>
            </json:object>
        </json:array> 
    </json:object>
</json:object>
    <alice xmlns="http://some-namespace" xmlns:charlie="http://some-other-namespace">
    <bob>david</bob>
    <charlie:edgar>frank</charlie:edgar>
</alice>
    {
   "alice":{
      "bob":{
         "$":"david",
         "@xmlns":{
            "charlie":"http:\/\/some-other-namespace",
            "$":"http:\/\/some-namespace"
         }
      },
      "charlie:edgar":{
         "$":"frank",
         "@xmlns":{
            "charlie":"http:\/\/some-other-namespace",
            "$":"http:\/\/some-namespace"
         }
      },
      "@xmlns":{
         "charlie":"http:\/\/some-other-namespace",
         "$":"http:\/\/some-namespace"
      }
   }
}

<json:object xmlns:json="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/2009/jsonx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.datapower.com/schemas/json jsonx.xsd">
    <json:object name="alice">
        <json:object name="bob">
            <json:string name="$">david</json:string>
            <json:object name="@xmlns">
                <json:string name="charlie">http://some-other-namespace</json:string>
                <json:string name="$">http://some-namespace</json:string>
            </json:object>
        </json:object>
        <json:object name="charlie:edgar">
            <json:string name="$">frank</json:string>
            <json:object name="@xmlns">
                <json:string name="charlie">http://some-other-namespace</json:string>
                <json:string name="$">http://some-namespace</json:string>
            </json:object>
        </json:object>
        <json:object name="@xmlns">
            <json:string name="charlie">http://some-other-namespace</json:string>
            <json:string name="$">http://some-namespace</json:string>
        </json:object>
    </json:object>
</json:object>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:json="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/2010/jsonx" xmlns:b="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/2009/jsonx" exclude-result-prefixes="json #default">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/json:object">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="json:array[@name]">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="noname">
            <xsl:with-param name="nme" select="name()"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="json:object" mode="noname">
        <xsl:param name="nme"/>
        <xsl:element name="{../@name}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="json:array">
        <xsl:element name="{../@name}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="json:object[@name]">
        <xsl:if test="not(*[namespace-uri()=''])">
            <xsl:element name="{@name}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
                <!--                <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[name()]"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>-->
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>
        <!--        <xsl:element name="{@name}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>-->
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="json:string[@name]">
        <xsl:if test="not(*[namespace-uri()=''])">
            <xsl:element name="{@name}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
                <def>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="namespace-uri-for-prefix(json)"/>
                </def>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="json:string">
        <xsl:element name="{../@name}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="json:number[@name]">
        <xsl:element name="{@name}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="json:null[@name]">
        <xsl:element name="{@name}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="json:boolean[@name]">
        <xsl:element name="{@name}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="json:boolean[@name]">
        <xsl:element name="{@name}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I need the output as below:

```
<Login>
    <Group>
        <Group>
            <Name>john</Name>
            <Password/>
        </Group>
        <Group>
            <Name>jack</Name>
            <Password/>
        </Group>
    </Group>
</Login>
```

I am using the below xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:func="http://exslt.org/functions" xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xslt" xmlns:json="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/2009/jsonx" xmlns:regexp="http://exslt.org/regular-expressions">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="/*[node()]">
        <xsl:text>{</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="detect"/>
        <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*" mode="detect">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="name(preceding-sibling::*[1]) = name(current()) and name(following-sibling::*[1]) != name(current())">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="obj-content"/>
                <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
                <xsl:if test="count(following-sibling::*[name() != name(current())]) &gt; 0">, </xsl:if>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="name(preceding-sibling::*[1]) = name(current())">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="obj-content"/>
                <xsl:if test="name(following-sibling::*) = name(current())">, </xsl:if>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="following-sibling::*[1][name() = name(current())]">
                <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
                <xsl:text>" : [</xsl:text>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="obj-content"/>
                <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="count(./child::*) > 0 or count(@*) > 0">
                <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="obj-content"/>
                <xsl:if test="count(following-sibling::*) &gt; 0">, </xsl:if>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="count(./child::*) = 0">
                <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : "<xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
                <xsl:if test="count(following-sibling::*) &gt; 0">, </xsl:if>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*" mode="obj-content">
        <xsl:text>{</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="attr"/>
        <xsl:if test="count(@*) &gt; 0 and (count(child::*) &gt; 0 or text())">, </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="./*" mode="detect"/>
        <xsl:if test="count(child::*) = 0 and text() and not(@*)">
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : "<xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="count(child::*) = 0 and text() and @*">
            <xsl:text>"text" : "</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
        <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">, </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*" mode="attr">
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : "<xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">,</xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node/@TEXT | text()" name="removeBreaks">
        <xsl:param name="pText" select="normalize-space(.)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="myVar" select="regexp:replace($pText,'\\','gi','\\')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="myVar2" select="regexp:replace($myVar,'&#x22;','gi','\&#x23;')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="myVar3" select="regexp:replace($myVar2,'&#x2F;','gi','&#x5C;&#x2F;')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="myVar4" select="regexp:replace($myVar3,'\t','gi','\t')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="myVar5" select="regexp:replace($myVar4,'\n','gi','\n')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="myVar6" select="regexp:replace($myVar5,'\r','gi','\r')"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not(contains($myVar6, '&#xA;'))">
                <xsl:copy-of select="$myVar6"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($myVar6, '&#xD;&#xA;'), ' ')"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="removeBreaks">
                    <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after($myVar6, '&#xD;&#xA;')"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here I am using the name as "object" in the template json:object but I need the arrayname,arrayname...so on.Could anyone please help me to get this output?

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-rsalz-jsonx-00#page-4
http://controlfreak.net/xml-to-json-in-xslt-a-toolkit/
[extracting information from a JSON file using XSLT version 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12188064/extracting-information-from-a-json-file-using-xslt-version-1-0)
http://badgerfish.ning.com/

Comment: Square brackets [ and ] are not valid in element names in XML. Are you sure this is what you require?

Comment: Also, your input XML contains `json:object` elements, which your current XSLT converts to just `object` elements, but these aren't actually shown in your output XML. Do you want your numbering on the `group` or `object` then? Thanks!

Comment: The numbering is not there also fine but I need the arrayname and the object that we are using in the array names to be same..

<Login>
    <Group><!-- Nameshould be same-->
        <Group><!-- Nameshould be same-->
            <Name>john</Name>
            <Password/>
        </Group>
        <Group>
            <Name>john</Name>
            <Password/>
        </Group>
    </Group>
</Login>

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok with this :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Login>
    <Group>
        <Group>
            <Name>john</Name>
            <Password/>
        </Group>
        <Group>
            <Name>john</Name>
            <Password/>
        </Group>
    </Group>
</Login>
```

Then the following works :-

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns:json="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/2009/jsonx" exclude-result-prefixes="json">
    <xsl:template match="/json:object">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="json:array[@name]">
        <xsl:element name="{@name}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="json:object">
        <xsl:element name="{../@name}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="json:string[@name]">
        <xsl:element name="{@name}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I want to specify that name in general way like if the array name is user I have to use the same name for the json:object element name aslo

Comment: Updated to pick the name from parent.

Comment: @Himanshu There is a template `match="json:object[@name]"` missing, which must generate elements for `object` input with specified names. See for example `Login` element in wish output.

Comment: Its working thank you...
I need one general xslt that converts XML to JSONX formate
"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892266/convert-xml-to-jsonx-using-xslt"
Could you please look into the below link and help me out to achieve..

Comment: @Himanshu,
Could you please look into this link "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892266/convert-xml-to-jsonx-using-xslt" and help me.