# convert xml to jsonx using xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, jsonx

Can anyone help me out in getting the below with an array..I have to generate the generalised xsl..
Input XML:

```
<Login>
    <Groups>
        <Group>
            <Name>john</Name>
            <Password/>
        </Group>
        <Group>
            <Name>john</Name>
            <Password/>
        </Group>
    </Groups>
</Login>
```

Output:

```
<json:object xmlns:json="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/2009/jsonx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <json:object name="Login">
        <json:object name="Groups">
            <json:array name="Group">
                <json:object>
                    <json:string name="Name">john</json:string>
                    <json:string name="Password"/>
                </json:object>
                <json:object>
                    <json:string name="Name">john</json:string>
                    <json:string name="Password"/>
                </json:object>
            </json:array>
        </json:object>
    </json:object>
</json:object>
```

Answer (score 2):

More generalized solution. Requires XSLT 2.0

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:json="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/2009/jsonx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="json:object">
            <xsl:apply-templates />    
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[*]">
        <xsl:param name="nodeName" select="name()" />
        <xsl:variable name="firstNodeName" select="name(*[1])" />

        <xsl:element name="json:object">
            <xsl:if test="$nodeName">
                <xsl:attribute name="name" select="$nodeName" />
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="(count(*) > 1) and (every $x in */name() satisfies $x=$firstNodeName)">
                    <xsl:element name="json:array">
                        <xsl:attribute name="name" select="$firstNodeName" />

                        <xsl:apply-templates >
                            <xsl:with-param name="nodeName" select="''" />
                        </xsl:apply-templates>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates />
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
        <xsl:element name="json:string">
            <xsl:attribute name="name">
                <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to the provided sample XML, produces following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<json:object xmlns:json="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/2009/jsonx">
    <json:object name="Login">
        <json:object name="Groups">
            <json:array name="Group">
                <json:object>
                    <json:string name="Name">john</json:string>
                    <json:string name="Password"></json:string>
                </json:object>
                <json:object>
                    <json:string name="Name">john</json:string>
                    <json:string name="Password"></json:string>
                </json:object>
            </json:array>
        </json:object>
    </json:object>
</json:object>
```

The above solution was tested on this site: http://xslttest.appspot.com/

EDIT:

`every $x in */name() satisfies $x=$firstNodeName` is XPATH 2.0 construction that checks if all the elements in `*/name()` sequence are equal to $firstNodeName. So this whole condition actually means checking if a node has more than one child with the same name - this is a condition for checking if we're dealing with `json:array` case.

Comment: Hi Baran,

Great thanks for your quick reply...
Is it possible to have the generalized xsl without mentioning the element names over there...

Comment: @user1731504 see my edit. I tried to adapt to 'rules' presented by your sample code. HTH

Comment: Hi Baran,
I had tried this but it is not genrating the objects
<json:object xmlns:json="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/2009/jsonx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <json:string name="xml-stylesheet"></json:string>
 <json:array name="Login">
  <json:array name="Groups">
   <json:object>
    <json:string name="Name">john</json:string>
    <json:string name="Password"></json:string>
   </json:object>
   <json:object>
    <json:string name="Name">john</json:string>
    <json:string name="Password"></json:string>
   </json:object>
  </json:array>
 </json:array>
</json:object>

Comment: Here it is giving this <json:array name="Login"> but it should produce <json:object name="Login">

Comment: Hi Baran,
Sorry for too many changes..
Is it possible to get the below formate
<json:object xmlns:json="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/2009/jsonx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <json:object name="Login">
 <json:object name="Groups">
  <json:array name="Group">
   <json:object>
    <json:string name="Name">john</json:string>
    <json:null name="Password"/>
   </json:object>
   <json:object>
    <json:string name="Name">john</json:string>
    <json:null name="Password"/>
   </json:object>
  </json:array>
 </json:object>
 </json:object>
</json:object>

Comment: @Baran--I have modified the required output in the question.
Could you please help me out to get the required formate..

Comment: Can't see a better way than suggested by @Baran

Comment: @user1731504 btw, my first name is Lukasz :)

Comment: @LukaszBaran--Thanks for the updated solution..
Could you please tell me what is meant by "every $x in */name() satisfies $x=$firstNodeName"..What is $x here?

Comment: @LukaszBaran-- Is it possible to do the same in v1.0 with generate-id()?

Comment: @LukaszBaran-- Could you please provide me the solution in v 1.0?

Answer (score 0):

you can try the below generic xslt :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:json="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/2009/jsonx" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- Array -->



<xsl:template match="*[*[2]][name(*[1])=name(*[2])]">


<json:object name="{name()}">


<json:array name="{name(*[1])}">

<xsl:apply-templates/>

</json:array>

</json:object>

</xsl:template>

<!-- Array member -->



<xsl:template match="*[parent::*[ name(*[1])=name(*[2]) ]] | /">


<json:object>

<xsl:apply-templates/>

</json:object>

</xsl:template>

<!-- Object -->



<xsl:template match="*">


<json:object name="{name()}">

<xsl:apply-templates/>

</json:object>

</xsl:template>

<!-- String -->



<xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">


<json:string name="{name()}">

<xsl:value-of select="."/>

</json:string>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:json="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/2009/jsonx">
<xsl:output indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
<!-- Array -->
<xsl:template match="*[*[2]][name(*[1])=name(*[2])]">
  <json:object name="{name()}">
    <json:array name="{name(*[1])}">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </json:array>
  </json:object>
</xsl:template>
<!-- Array member -->
<xsl:template match="*[parent::*[ name(*[1])=name(*[2]) ]] | /">
  <json:object>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </json:object>
</xsl:template>
<!-- Object -->
<xsl:template match="*">
  <json:object name="{name()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </json:object>
</xsl:template>
<!-- String -->
<xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
  <json:string name="{name()}">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </json:string>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Some explanation about the code or links to related documentation for insights and learning is often helpful for the author.